# Value counts of connected names

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to transform this PySpark dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("A", 1),
  ("A", 2), 
  ("A", 3),
  ("B", 1),
  ("B", 2),
  ("B", 4), 
  ("B", 5)
],
  ["name", "connect"]
)

df.show()
+----+-------+
|name|connect|
+----+-------+
|   A|      1|
|   A|      2|
|   A|      3|
|   B|      1|
|   B|      2|
|   B|      4|
|   B|      5|
+----+-------+
```

Into the following format:

```
df_out = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("A", "A", 3),
  ("B", "B", 4), 
  ("A", "B", 2)
],
  ["name1", "name2", "n_connect"]
)

df_out.show()
+-----+-----+---------+
|name1|name2|n_connect|
+-----+-----+---------+
|    A|    A|        3|
|    B|    B|        4|
|    A|    B|        2|
+-----+-----+---------+
```

I.e. I want to know how many "connections" each name has, and I want to know how many shared "connections" there are between each name. Is there any standard function in Spark that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a self-join, merge the identical combinations, i.e. A->B and B->A and then countDistinct `connect` for each combination. below we use `sort_array(array(d1.name, d2.name))` to group the unique name combinations:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import countDistinct

df_new = df.alias("d1").join(df.alias("d2"), "connect") \
    .selectExpr("sort_array(array(d1.name, d2.name)) as names", "d1.connect") \
    .groupby("names") \
    .agg(countDistinct("connect").alias("n_connect"))
+------+---------+
| names|n_connect|
+------+---------+
|[A, A]|        3|
|[B, B]|        4|
|[A, B]|        2|
+------+---------+

df_new.selectExpr("names[0] as name1", "names[1] as name2", "n_connect").show()
+-----+-----+---------+
|name1|name2|n_connect|
+-----+-----+---------+
|    A|    A|        3|
|    B|    B|        4|
|    A|    B|        2|
+-----+-----+---------+
```

you can do the similar with pandas:

```
pdf = df.toPandas()
pdf.merge(pdf, on="connect") \
    .assign(names=lambda x: [tuple(sorted(z)) for z in zip(x.name_x, x.name_y)]) \
    .groupby('names')["connect"].nunique()
#Out[*]:
#names
#(A, A)    3
#(A, B)    2
#(B, B)    4
```

Per **@anky**'s suggestion, use np.sort() to sort names:

```
import numpy as np
names = ["name_x", "name_y"]
pdf1 = pdf.merge(pdf, on="connect")
pdf1[names] = np.sort(pdf1[names],1)
pdf1.groupby(names)["connect"].nunique().reset_index()
#  name_x name_y  connect
#0      A      A        3
#1      A      B        2
#2      B      B        4
```